# MySQL Match Against and Group by Multiple terms

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have data available appears in comments. The comments actually about skills like PHP, Java etc etc.

Now I want to use Match Against in such a way that I could find total records grouped by skills. So for instance if I match data against certain skills then data should be displayed as:

```
Skills    Total
..................
Java     10
PHP       5
```

Something like that.

Comment: What is the source of the list of Skills?  Do you have a Skills table containing a row giving each name?

Comment: Umm.. yeah that would be in a table/array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcea4/1

```
SELECT skill, sum(comment REGEXP skill)
FROM comments,skills
GROUP BY skill
```

Comment: looks amazing, will it be efficient? The column is of type *text* and have *Full Text* search

Comment: Should be Ok, but of course data volume can affect solution as always.

Comment: Does it make an exact match? in Original data I find more occurrence of a term than returned by the query. For instance it's omitting *Javascript*

Comment: Ok just rechecked, the query is always returning lesser occurrences then actual.

Comment: Do you really need to count all occurrences even if there are several the same per comment?

Comment: I don't know how do I send you entire Content of Database

Comment: No, only one occurrence per Comment is suffice. Is it doing that?

Comment: Yes, it is one occurrence per Comment.

Comment: Actually I just rechecked, even there are one occurence of a term, it's being skipped.

Comment: Comment Data, https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35231160/RawComments.sql.zip  you already had created Skills table structure

Comment: what's it making difference?

Comment: JS and javascript are counted as one skill.

Comment: This is, of course, going to do a full table scan of the comment table.

Comment: Yes, it is better to do once per comment and update counter somewhere.

Comment: Sorry I could not reply earlier. Even terms like Python are being counted less.

Comment: For now you need exact match with alias in order to count it. If you can show data where query is not working - we can check.

Comment: This is the original source of comments:(http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3412900) - This is the query I am running to get data of this particular HN URL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7472